# filter the json upto count 10 in javascript/ typescript

Tags: javascript, object, nested

> I have a nested json object with parent, child, subchild and so on.
> The object is dynamic and can have child or subchild or can have none

```
    {
          total_count: 22,
          data: [
            {
              ticket_id: "1",
              ticket_summary: "Ticket one",
              count: 2,
              child: [
                {
                  ticket_id: "1-1",
                  ticket_summary: "Ticket child",
                  count: 0,
                  child: [],
                },
                {
                  ticket_id: "1-2",
                  ticket_summary: "Ticket child",
                  count: 0,
                  child: [],
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              ticket_id: "2",
              ticket_summary: "Ticket two",
              count: 2,
              child: [
                {
                  ticket_id: "2-1",
                  ticket_summary: "Ticket child",
                  count: 0,
                  child: [],
                },
                {
                  ticket_id: "2-2",
                  ticket_summary: "Ticket child",
                  count: 0,
                  child: [],
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              ticket_id: "3",
              ticket_summary: "Ticket three",
              count: 2,
              child: [
                {
                  ticket_id: "3-1",
                  ticket_summary: "Ticket child",
                  count: 2,
                  child: [
                    {
                      ticket_id: "3-1-1",
                      ticket_summary: "Ticket sub child",
                      count: 1,
                      child: [
                       {
                        ticket_id: "3-1-1-1",
                        ticket_summary: "Ticket sub sub child",
                        count: 0,
                        child: []
                       }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      ticket_id: "3-1-2",
                      ticket_summary: "Ticket sub child",
                      count: 0,
                      child: [],
                    },
                  ],
                },
                {
                  ticket_id: "3-2",
                  ticket_summary: "Ticket child",
                  count: 0,
                  child: [],
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              ticket_id: '4',
              ticket_summary: 'Ticket 4',
              child: []
            },
            {
              ticket_id: '5',
              ticket_summary: 'Ticket 5',
              child: [
                {
                  ticket_id: "5-1",
                  ticket_summary: "Ticket child",
                  child: [],
                },
                {
                  ticket_id: "5-2",
                  ticket_summary: "Ticket child",
                  child: [],
                },
              ]
            },
```

> and I want the json object upto count 10 like this
> As the 'ticket_id: 3-1-1-1' is the 10th child in hierarchy.

```
    {
          total_count: 22,
          data: [
            {
              ticket_id: "1",
              ticket_summary: "Ticket one",
              count: 2,
              child: [
                {
                  ticket_id: "1-1",
                  ticket_summary: "Ticket child",
                  count: 0,
                  child: [],
                },
                {
                  ticket_id: "1-2",
                  ticket_summary: "Ticket child",
                  count: 0,
                  child: [],
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              ticket_id: "2",
              ticket_summary: "Ticket two",
              count: 2,
              child: [
                {
                  ticket_id: "2-1",
                  ticket_summary: "Ticket child",
                  count: 0,
                  child: [],
                },
                {
                  ticket_id: "2-2",
                  ticket_summary: "Ticket child",
                  count: 0,
                  child: [],
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              ticket_id: "3",
              ticket_summary: "Ticket three",
              count: 2,
              child: [
                {
                  ticket_id: "3-1",
                  ticket_summary: "Ticket child",
                  count: 2,
                  child: [
                    {
                      ticket_id: "3-1-1",
                      ticket_summary: "Ticket sub child",
                      count: 1,
                      child: [
                       {
                        ticket_id: "3-1-1-1",
                        ticket_summary: "Ticket sub sub child",
                        count: 0,
                        child: []
                       }
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                }
              ],
            }
          ]
}
```

> I am able to get the count by iterating over it but could't filter the object.

```
    getCount(ticket, count) {
      ticket.child.map(childTicket => {
        count++;
        // if (count === 10) {
        //   return count;
        // }
        if (childTicket.child.length > 0) {
          count = this.getCount(childTicket, count);
        }
      });
      return count;
    },


    getChildTicketCount() {
      let counter = 0;
      this.state.tickets.data.map(ticket => {
        counter++;
        if (ticket.child.length > 0) {
          const count = this.getCount(ticket, counter);
          counter = count;
        }
      });
      return counter;
    }
```

> Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could write a depth first walk function that takes a function (callback) as parameter ; this walk function could then be used to either count and list/filter the data by providing a different callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the data stucture by takeing a count for each nested arrays and stop taking nested if if it reaches zero.

```js
function getCount(array, count) {
    const
        fn = (c => (r, o) => {
            if (c.count && c.count--) r.push({ ...o, child: o.child.reduce(fn, []) });
            return r;
        })({ count });

    return array.reduce(fn, []);
}

var data = { total_count: 22, data: [{ ticket_id: "1", ticket_summary: "Ticket one", count: 2, child: [{ ticket_id: "1-1", ticket_summary: "Ticket child", count: 0, child: [] }, { ticket_id: "1-2", ticket_summary: "Ticket child", count: 0, child: [] }] }, { ticket_id: "2", ticket_summary: "Ticket two", count: 2, child: [{ ticket_id: "2-1", ticket_summary: "Ticket child", count: 0, child: [] }, { ticket_id: "2-2", ticket_summary: "Ticket child", count: 0, child: [] }] }, { ticket_id: "3", ticket_summary: "Ticket three", count: 2, child: [{ ticket_id: "3-1", ticket_summary: "Ticket child", count: 2, child: [{ ticket_id: "3-1-1", ticket_summary: "Ticket sub child", count: 1, child: [{ ticket_id: "3-1-1-1", ticket_summary: "Ticket sub sub child", count: 0, child: [] }] }, { ticket_id: "3-1-2", ticket_summary: "Ticket sub child", count: 0, child: [] }] }, { ticket_id: "3-2", ticket_summary: "Ticket child", count: 0, child: [] }], }, { ticket_id: '4', ticket_summary: 'Ticket 4', child: [] }, { ticket_id: '5', ticket_summary: 'Ticket 5', child: [{ ticket_id: "5-1", ticket_summary: "Ticket child", child: [] }, { ticket_id: "5-2", ticket_summary: "Ticket child", child: [] },] }] },
    result = { ...data, data: getCount(data.data, 10) };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```